# App is crashing when using AVAudioplayer continuously xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

My Xamarin.Ios app is crashing when I play sounds using **AVAudioPlayer continously**. I'm also using a **Captuvo scanner** to scan bar codes and play sounds according to the barcode scanned.

At a time i may need to **play 3 or more sounds one by one**. So i use **Finished Launching method of AVAudioPlayer** so play sound one by one.

the app is working perfectly when scanned slowly, but when scanned with more speed the app crashes. Here is the crash log.

> Incident Identifier: 8AC6F9C2-EEB2-4E11-A618-C6F6B82F759C
>   CrashReporter Key:   1ea5f3b8e74c13c25fde44ab839109c4d5380982
>   Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
>   OS Version:          iPhone OS 8.2 (12D508)
>   Kernel version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Mon Feb  9 22:07:50 PST 2015; root:xnu-2783.5.38~5/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8942X
>   Date:                2015-08-25 12:03:42 +0530
>   Exception Code:      0xdeaffeed
>   **`Reason:Power assertion timeout for "com.apple.timed.ntp".  Simply releasing it now.`**
>   Backtrace for power assertion: pid 32 (0x280c8d57 0x280c921b 0xabf05 0xabbf5 0x31914c83 0x31914c6f 0x31920553 0x23789891 0x23787fb1 0x236d4b51 0x236d4963 0x24438611 0x244868c5 0x9af17 0x31952aaf)

Appreciate a solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose the problem.  You might need to post either more detailed logs (the above do not look related), or post a full sample